# wget, self-signed certs and a custom HTTPS server

Tags: https, openssl, wget, self-signed

For various reasons I have created a simple HTTP server, and added SSL support via OpenSSL.  I'm using self-signed certificates.  IE, Firefox and Chrome happily load content as long as I add the CA to the trusted root CAs.

However, wget (even when using the `--no-check-certificate` flag) reports:

```
OpenSSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

If I run the OpenSSL client against my server using:

```
openssl s_client -connect dnvista:82 -debug
```

I get back:
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
and then

```
5852:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:.\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1060:SSL alert number 40
5852:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:.\ssl\s23_lib.c:188:
```

Do wget and the OpenSSL client simply not work with self-signed certificates?

**UPDATE:**

For anyone that comes along later, adding this code helped with the OpenSSL client and Firefox:

```
EC_KEY *ecdh = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh(ctx, ecdh);
EC_KEY_free(ecdh);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I checked the man page of `wget`, and `--no-check-certificate` only seems to affect the **server certificate**. You need to specify your self-signed certificate as a valid CA certificate locally.

To do this, specify the certificate as `--ca-certificate=...` in `wget` and `-CAfile` in the `s_client` case.

Comment: Hi.  I've seen a lot of comments like these, "Turn the check-off" in as many words.  It is a **really _BAD_  idea**.  A bit like street racing with bald tyres on wet roads.  I'm disappointed this answer got a 'tick' mark.

Comment: will: I agree, turning the check of is generally a bad idea. My answer suggests one way of making the CA certificate known to the client, so that the check can be performed correctly.

Answer (score 6):

You can also install trusted root CA certificates into OpenSSL in one of a number of ways:

- Put your CA certificate in /etc/pki/tls/certs or equivalent directory, then create a link based on the certificate hash.  See http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml#ca-openssl for details.
- Append your CA certificate to /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt, /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem, or equivalent CA bundle.

Comment: I posted a question: [Ruby OpenSSL Set-up or Configuration for your Application Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233169/ruby-openssl-set-up-or-configuration-for-your-application-code), to ask _HOW_ Ruby gets the PEM or CRT resources to do host-verification.  I've exhaustively looked for a module that loads environment or configuration information with recursive **grep** scans -- No luck (except in test and samples).