# SSL: get artifact on Nexus using HTTPS

Tags: ssl, nexus

I have a server that runs Nexus, I can get access to Nexus and download artifacts via https (browser) without problem.

Now I want to get the artifact using `wget` via https:

```
wget https://195.20.100.100:8081/repository/myrepo/com/myrepo/program/1.0-SNAPSHOT/program.tar.gz
```

and it tells me :

```
WARNING: cannot verify 195.20.100.100's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/ST=Unspecified/L=Unspecified/O=Sonatype/OU=Example/CN=*.195.20.100.100’:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
```

I want to know the exact steps I have to do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Nexus Repository Manager issue per se, I believe you just need to do something akin to the answer in this post: [wget, self-signed certs and a custom HTTPS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644622/wget-self-signed-certs-and-a-custom-https-server)